# Kernel 3.13.0-63-lowlatency - All up-to-date - Error at open firefox 40: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

Tags: firefox

After update my system and reboot, at open Firefox I receive this error return:

```
[33] 05:57:27 sergio@freya ~
$ firefox

(process:8010): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
```

How to resolve this ?
I'm searching how to install pantheon-filechooser-module, but not found the solution.

Comment: The warning about the file chooser module is erroneous. You will get this with any legacy gtk2 or qt app. It is a non-fatal warning.

Comment: Than the firefox not opens becouse the GLib-CRITICAL error ?

Comment: I'm not sure. To be honest, I get the same Glib error opening Firefox 40.0.3 and it works fine. But I know for sure that the gtk module warning is not it

Comment: Did you by accident use freshplayerplugin for flash? There was bugged commit that made to the ppa recently, caused launch crashes of firefox.

Comment: That GLib error should be fixed in Firefox 42 ([source](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=833117#c128))

Comment: After some updates in all packages of system the Firefox back to run fine, version 40.0.3. Thanks for all!